# Understanding return type of dict:fetch in erlang

Tags: erlang

I create a dictionary using two different ways, then I get the result, but I have two different results.
I would like to understand why.

using *dict:append*

```
Dict1 = dict:append(key, value, dict:new()).
dict:fetch(key, Dict1).
% I get a list with the value
[value]
```

using *dict:from_list*

```
Dict2 = dict:from_list([{ key, value }]).
dict:fetch(key, Dict2).
% I get the value
value
```

Why the return type is different ?
[fetch doc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dict.html#fetch-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dict:append/3`'s documentation says:

> Appends a new Value to the current list of values associated with Key.

It's meant to be used when the values of the dict are always lists. You can see that `Dict1` is a dict from `key` to `[value]` while `Dict2` is a dict from `key` to `value`:

```
> dict:to_list(Dict1).
[{key,[value]}]
> dict:to_list(Dict2).
[{key,value}]
```

If you want to store a value as-is and not in a list, you can use `dict:store/3`:

```
> Dict3 = dict:store(key, value, dict:new()).
{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,
      {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
      {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
        [[key|value]],
        [],[],[],[],[],[]}}}
> dict:fetch(key, Dict3).
value
```

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert. If I don't know how was created the dictionary, is very hard to get the real value, I need to get the result, verify if is a list, take the element, ..... Do you know an easy way?. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to get the first element of the list if the value is a list, otherwise keep the original value?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that. But ideally I would like to constrain to have only one value for each key.